# Не правильный вывод

Tags: jquery

Почему всегда выводит 2? Я думаю что в условии дело, как проверять `key` какой нажал пользователь?

```
$.contextMenu({
    selector: '.context-menu-one',
    items: {
        open: {name: 'Открыть', icon: 'open'},
        save:  {name: 'Сохранить', icon: 'save'},
    },
    callback: function(key, options) {
    if(key == open){
            $('#res').html('Выбрана команда 1');
        }
        else{
            $('#res').html('Выбрана команда 2');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Что это у Вас за плагин? Документация на него есть?

Comment: Есть, http://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/ Но я не нашел, там только вывод через alert + key

Comment: вам точно надо сранивать не `key == 'open'` а  именно `== open`, т.е. не со строкой а переменной?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[документация вам гласит следующее](https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/docs/items.html#callback):

> **callback**
>   Specifies the default callback to be used in case an item does not
>   expose its own callback. The default callback behaves just like
>   item.callback.

Что означает, что глобальное свойство callback определяет действие по умолчанию, когда элементы коллекции `items` не имеют своего собственного обработчика.

Для элементов items обработчик объявляется следующим образом

> Specifies the callback to execute if clicked on.
>   The Callback is executed in the context of the triggering object. **The
>   first argument is the key of the command**. The second argument is the
>   options object. The Callback may return false to prevent the menu from
>   being hidden.

отсюда следует, что первый аргумент вашего обработчика это ключ команды. Следовательно, в вашем коде  надо проверять строковое значение ключа `key == "open"`, а не непонятную переменную `open`:

```
callback: function(key, options) {
             if(key == "open"){
                 ....
         }
```